# What's the hbase equivalent to the Oracle sample clause?

Tags: sql, oracle, hbase

In Oracle you can take a sample of a dataset like so:

```
select * from table sample(10);
```

What's the equivalent to this in HBase?

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no equivalent to Oracle's `sample` syntax.

Comment: Wouldn't this just limit the number of results to 10?

Comment: There's no way to simulate it either?